# Unable to run Jboss data grid server in cluster mode

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I'm new to Jboss Redhat data grid. Setting up Jboss data grid 8.3.1 based on redhat documentation as below:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/8.3/html/data_grid_server_guide/server-getting-started

I followed the steps in the documentation, but facing an error while running a second instance of server in the cluster as below:

Cannot read /root/Datagrid/datagrid-8.3.1/bin/server2/conf/log4j2.xml

Please guide me to resolve this issue